# Logging value from promise .then() shows data but when returning it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a function that uses the refresh token I have to get a new access token and I want to use this function before every call that requires an access token.

The first function `refreshAccessToken()` makes the request and returns the response including the body that contains the new access token. Now I thought this was enough but I was getting `undefined` followed by the actual data and doing some digging I found this question:

[Promise returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315450/promise-returns-undefined)

which led me to returning the value from this function so the promise resolves fully and using it in another, `returnAccessToken()`.

`returnAccessToken()` is supposed to take the resolved promise value and return the access token but it behaves unexpectedly. The `console.log` line works like a charm and it logs the correct value everytime but when I return the token and try to use it in the function below it, it is undefined again.

**api.js**

```
"use strict"

const request = require("request-promise-native");

refreshAccessToken: async function (credentialsObject) {
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        uri: <refresh token uri>,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        json: true
    };

    return await request(options);
},

returnAccessToken: function (auth) {
    this.refreshAccessToken(auth)
        .then(function (result) {
            // This logs the result correctly
            console.log(result.body);

            return result.body;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
},

actionRequiringAccessToken: function (auth) {
    let tokens = this.returnAccessToken(auth);
    // This returns undefined
    console.log(tokens);
}
```

**index.js**

Also yes I realize that logging here does nothing as I don't currently return a value I just include it because this is how `actionThatRequiresAccessToken()` is run in my setup.

```
"use strict"

const api = require("api");

let auth = {
    // Credentials
};

api.actionRequiringAccessToken(auth)
    .then(function (data)) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: the answer provide by @Jonas W. is correct, but I would suggest make `actionRequiringAccessToken` async function and await for `refreshAccessToken` in it, then do wahtever with the result. (you need to wait for `tokens` in both situation anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Just add return in returnAccessToken method.. you are not returning anything

`returnAccessToken: function (auth) {
    return this.refreshAccessToken(auth)`

Answer (score 0):

```
  return result.body;
```

That returns the data *into* the `.then` chain. So actually your method doesnt return anything. Might add a return here:

```
 returnAccessToken: function (auth) {
   return this.refreshAccessToken(auth) /*...*0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make `actionRequiringAccessToken` async and drop `returnAccessToken`

```
actionRequiringAccessToken: async function (auth) {
    let response = await this.returnAccessToken(auth);
    let tokens = response.body //parse the response... whatever returnAccessToken does
    console.log(tokens);
}
```